# Too many redirects: Clearing cookies doesn't work

Tags: magento, redirect, cookies

I have a machine where Magento is deployed. The admin page  redirected to itself so many times and now I am unable to get the admin page. I get the too many redirects error. I have already tried clearing the cookies, also made some changes in the magento configuration.

I have tried accessing the admin page from other machines, but it works fine. The problem is only on one particular machine. What possibilities could be tried to resolve the issue? There are no troubles with other sites. [image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not even the problem with one machine, but with chrome on this machine. Try incognito mode - if works there try https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/YzvpLaOmVrY (if it doesn't - check if any of your extensions is allowed to work in incognito mode)

Comment: do you have any plugins running in the incognito mode?